# Why won't my js file run?

Tags: javascript

I have this in the html:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>asgmt6</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/asgmt6.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/linkHandler.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li><a id="home" href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
   </ul> 
</div>
```

my file path is right as it is in the js folder thats in the same folder as the html file.

Here is my js file which is called linkHandler.js and all it does is load the page, run the file, and when clicking the link displays the message. Now I have it that same as the book, but it does not work at all.

```
var HomeLink =
{
init: function()
{
    var link = document.getElementById("home");
    link.onclick = HomeLink.clickHandler;
},
clickHandler: function()
{
alert("Didn't think so....");
}
};

Core.start(HomeLink);
```

Comment: Please use FireBug plugin of Firefox and check for the JS error

Answer (score 3):

You're using an object called `Core` that wasn't defined anywhere.
Presumably it's in another file you forgot to include.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using firefox, open Error Console Window.
There is an error in your script.

```
Timestamp: 22/02/2013 13:58:55
Error: ReferenceError: Core is not defined
Source File: file:///C:/Users/iswanto/Desktop/linkHandler.js
Line: 14
```

Which refer to : `Core.start(HomeLink);`